# Is MsMq the standard when building SOA type applications?

Tags: c#, msmq

Is MsMq the standard message queue that is used when building SOA type applications?

The open source world has quite a few options, do MS shops stick with msmq (or are there other commercial ones that are also popular?)

Answer (score 1):

Typically, in an MS shop that is using a Queue (queue != SOA, btw), they will tend to use MSMQ.  It works nicely with WCF/BizTalk/Etc.

Whether that is a 'standard' or 'just something people do' is probably up for debate, but it is probably the most frequently used solution (again: for a specifically MS shop).

Comment: If queue != SOA then what = SOA?

Comment: SOA = 'Service Oriented Architecture' it refers to a coding model wherein functionality is broken down into chunks (services) and those chunks are assembled, lego-like, to build the specific functionality sets you need.  SOA uses Web Services via HTTP far more often, in my experience, than a queue.

Comment: Thanks for that. Have you heard of Udi Dahan? I recommend this webcast - http://vimeo.com/5022174

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ is an open-source solution with commercial support that works well on all sorts of platforms including MS, for what it's worth.